# Issue with metricbeat data visualization in OpenSearch dashboards

Tags: opensearch, metricbeat, opensearch-dashboards

Metricbeat sent some data through logstash into opensearch.
After first hit I set proper Index Pattern to read incoming data:

[image: system.cpu.pct Index Pattern]

[image: incoming datasets with system.cpu.pct]

Everything looks fine until I want to create a vizualization (line chart or table) for this data:
[image: Line chart for system.cpu.pct]

Looks like there is some issue with this data format (?), however I tried to set this parameter as well as number but got the same result. What more I have to set to get proper chart for this data?

- I changed Index Pattern settings but nothing happend
- I tried to use another similar property (system.cpu.system.pct) but got the same result

Comment: have you selected the correct time window?

Comment: yup, as you can see in ss above, there are several columns in selected time scope but with value 0

Comment: could you please share the mapping of the index?

Comment: @glenacota

Okay, so that problem appeard when I built logstash and opensearch on localhost through docker-compose.yml, however finally I got a VM so I deployed all over there and looks like there is no problem with data visualization. I also used a filter for this property before dashboard creation.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkNgE.png

Unfortunately I don't have that localhost state saved somewhere but I suppose that map shouldn't changed because it wasn't modified by anyone.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jy2Qi.png

Comment: okay, problem occured again, but this time I see that mapping for this property is wrong, and type is long instead of float:
`{
  "metricbeat-7.10.0-2023.03.09" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "host.cpu.pct" : {
        "full_name" : "host.cpu.pct",
        "mapping" : {
          "pct" : {
            "type" : "long"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`

Comment: however I can't change it manually. May it be a problem with logstash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so the problem was automapping of that property.
When I introduced a template before indices were created, the data looks fine.

`GET _index_template/metricbeats-template`
[image]

`GET metricbeat-7.10.0-2023.03.09/_mapping/field/host.cpu.pct`

[image]

[image]